# Help with creating a private method

Tags: java

I am working on a project and have the following psuedocode:

```
// create a private method, getIntValDialog, that returns an integer value and accepts
// two string values as arguments
    // declare and initialize a string variable, sValue, to an empty string
    // Accept input to sValue from a Input Dialog using smessage, stitle, and a question icon as arguments
    // return the integer converted value of sValue
        // end getIntValDialog method
```

I have an idea, but I don't quite understand how to set this up properly. The psuedocode tells me what I have to do, but I just need some help understanding and visualizing how this works. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I'd mark this is homework - it surely has that feel.  Bad pseudo code from a professor who's never written code for a living, and a student who can't follow it.

Comment: what do yo want to know? you should write a method that asks the user for input and then returns that input as an integer. the method takes 2 params: the title and message for the input dialog. stupid pseudocode

Comment: Homework question, with zero background work or attempts provided. Sorry but that is a -1.

Comment: Yes it is homework. I'm new with Java and I just wanted help and I didn't think to tag it as homework. I said it was a project. I didn't show what I attempted because all I did was create the method and wasn't sure about the guts of the method. But I understand it a bit clearer now, so thank you. Though I didn't think all the negative votes was quite necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I get out of your pseudo-code:

```
// create a private method, getIntValDialog, that returns an integer value and accepts 
// two string values as arguments
private int getIntValDialog(String smessage, String stitle)
{
     // declare and initialize a string variable, sValue, to an empty string
     String sValue = "";

     // Accept input to sValue from a Input Dialog using smessage, stitle,
     //  and a question icon as arguments
     // TODO (this is your part of the task)

     // return the integer converted value of sValue
     return Integer.valueOf(sValue);

// end getIntValDialog method
}
```

You take it from here.

> I have an idea, but I don't quite
>   understand how to set this up
>   properly.

Some advice for future questions: If you truly do have an idea, please post it as best you can and let people correct any errors.  It'll show good faith effort that you're working.

Comment: the access modifier should probably be `private`

Comment: I understand... thank you though, that helped me understand it a lot better.

Comment: Yup, going too fast, and habits took over.  I'll correct it.

Comment: If you decompose each statement of the given task and really teach this stuff instead of just giving the codes, I'll upvote you.

Comment: It's hard to see how much more detailed I can get.  It's probably not worth a vote to me.